# Tab Like Buttons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs

Is it Possible to make a tab like this?? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/36/tabcontrol.jpg/

I want it to become a button and show a different panel. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid, Where column 0 is your buttons and column 1 is your panel where your stuff goes. For control use user defined controls, and then on button click change accordingly.

By the way which technology is it ? Win forms, wpf, silverlight ... ?

Comment: Sir, thank for your help but what I want is like a vertical tab thingy. I want when the buttons were clicked it will show the details in the same form just like a normal tab. but vertically

Comment: @warook Can you please say which technology you're working with ? Win forms, wpf, silverlight any other ?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy to accomplish with jQuery (or just JavaScript), do some homework this is basic knowledge, widely spread on the internet...

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

or a fixed tutorial:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/

Comment: btw, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 sir. T_T